# Rosrun as super user

Tags: catkin, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have some code in my ros node (within a catkin workspace) that requires super user privilege in order to access some serial ports. How can this be done as sudo does not work with rosrun.

Thanks.

Edit: This is using the admin account:

```
$groups ros
ros : ros adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189457/rosrun-as-super-user/) by [trc123](https://answers.ros.org/users/19932/trc123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-08-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-08-08**:
How about you try to open the ports in .bashrc file ?

**Comment by [trc123](https://answers.ros.org/users/19932/trc123/) on 2014-08-08**:
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should really not use `sudo` with rosrun. It leads to all sorts of nastiness with permissions.

For serial ports (and access to other hardware through `/dev/xxx`) you just need to give the relevant user (most likely your user) access to the device file (fi: `/dev/ttyS0`). This is not ROS specific.

See [How do I allow a non-default user to use serial device ttyUSB0?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/112568/how-do-i-allow-a-non-default-user-to-use-serial-device-ttyusb0) on the Ubuntu stack-exchange for instance.

For ROS specific answers: [google: linux serial ports udev access](https://www.google.nl/?q=site:answers.ros.org+serial+ports+denied), which gives you:

- [port problems for not being root](http://answers.ros.org/question/12821/port-problems-for-not-being-root/)
- [Can't access turtlebot through ttyUSB0](http://answers.ros.org/question/11185/cant-access-turtlebot-through-ttyusb0/)
- [Failed to open port /dev/ttyUSB0](http://answers.ros.org/question/46790/failed-to-open-port-devttyusb0/)

---

Edit: and just for completeness (and for the lazy), a quote from the first answer to the question on the Ubuntu stack-exchange:

> As you've noticed, the `/dev/ttyUSB0` device has the group of `dialout`. All you need to do is add the second user to the `dialout` group:

> `sudo adduser USERNAME dialout`

Note: you need to log out and back in for your user groups to be reloaded.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [trc123](https://answers.ros.org/users/19932/trc123/) on 2014-08-08**:
Thank you, I needed to rebooting.